# undefined method `val' for #<Arel::Nodes::BindParam:0x007fa13ef32028>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am new to rails, and cannot figure out that why do I get the error specified above when I try to create a new application after login.

Also, while I was looking at solutions online, I found there was something wrong with the foreign key. therefore, I removed the foreign key and added it again using migration. However, the schema.rb file that is shown below does not show an index, but does show Student_id column.

Questions :

1. Should creation of has_one and belongs_to association require one to mention it in routes.rb as well . ( I read online it does require, but why ? )
2. How to decide where to place belongs_to and has_one.
3. How to find out where the above error is generated from ?

Model Student ( created using devise )

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      has_one :student_application

end
```

StudentApplication ( Generate using scaffold)

```
class StudentApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Student

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :student_applications

  devise_for :students

  root to: "student_applications#index"
end
```

In the controller student_application_controller.rb

```
def new
  #@student_application = StudentApplication.new
  @student_application = current_student.build_student_application()
end

def create
  #@student_application = StudentApplication.new(student_application_params)
  #@new_student = Student.find(params[:id])
  @student_application = current_student.create_student_application(student_application_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @student_application.save
      format.html { redirect_to @student_application, notice: 'Student application was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @student_application }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @student_application.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
def student_application_params
  params.require(:student_application).permit(:Student_id, :name, :phone, :email_id, :gpa)
end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "student_applications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "email_id"
    t.decimal  "gpa"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "Student_id"
  end

  create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "students", ["email"], name: "index_students_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "students", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_students_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?